# Get Windows Long Time Format

Tags: windows

I'm trying to get the long time format in Windows (like "hh:mm:ss tt"). I can get the short time format like this:

```
GetLocaleInfoEx(NULL, LOCALE_STIMEFORMAT, format, 100);
```

I can't seem to find a constant for `LOCALE_LTIMEFORMAT` or anything like that. I can get the short time, short date and long date, but how can I query the current user's **long time** format?

Comment: If you open the "Region" settings in Windows, you can see there are 2 values there, one for Short Time and one for Long Time. The user can configure them to be whatever they want, but Windows doesn't provide a way to read the format of the Long Time string.

Comment: tried http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12568/Format-Date-and-Time-As-Per-User-s-Locale-Settings ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, windows defines the 'long' time format by `LOCALE_STIMEFORMAT` (set to something like "hh:mm:ss"), and the short time as `LOCALE_SSHORTTIME` (which, according to MSDN, is valid for Windows 7 and later).

Does that correspond to your findings, i.e. does it match the user preference in the Region and Language Control Panel item?

For the `t` specifier, if it is not included into the locale format, then either you are left with always using a custom format (like gbjbaanb said), or perhaps examining the format string for the presence of `t` or `tt`, and if absent adding it yourself (though, this might lead to odd results for cultures expecting the `tt` before the general time, for instance). This should not be necessary though, as the time format used by the locale is responsible for yielding time-strings that make sense (distinguishing between AM and PM, for instance).

Comment: Thanks, LOCALE_STIMEFORMAT was the missing piece. I use this with GetLocaleInfoEx, then pass the returned format to GetTimeFormatEx with the TIME_NOSECONDS flag. Other people answered this as well, but you were the first, so points for you.  :)

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is already included in LOCALE_STIMEFORMAT.  Sample code:

```
wchar_t format[80];         // 80 is always enough
int ret = GetLocaleInfoEx(
    LOCALE_NAME_USER_DEFAULT,
    LOCALE_STIMEFORMAT,
    format, 
    sizeof(format) / sizeof(*format));
if (ret == 0) die(GetLastError());
std::wcout << format << std::endl;
```

Output on my machine (I live in the USA):

> h:mm:ss tt

The "tt" part will be absent for any culture or locale customization that does not display the AM/PM designator.

Answer (score 2):

The `LOCALE_STIMEFORMAT` is the long time format. To get the short time format you can use [`LOCALE_SSHORTTIME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373891) starting with Windows 7 or [cut off the seconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373891).

To confirm this simply change the long time format in your Control Panel / Region and Language settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try using it with the LOCALE_S1159 and LOCALE_2359 constants which return the text for the AM/PM designators.

I think the issue is that time format is a time format, down to the second. You have to format it yourself if you want AM/PM just like you do with daylight savings time or timezone indicators.

Comment: I just want to read the format that the user has selected, I can't assume that they have included AM/PM in their format.